# Springboot 2: Is there any way to configure TestRestTemplate to only use HTTP/2 protocol?

Tags: rest, unit-testing, spring-boot, http2

I am trying to test a microservice and want to ensure it works with http 2.0, as it is a requirement.

We have a lot of tests using TestRestTemplate, and I would like to reuse them, but I have been unable to find the way to configure TestRestTemplate to use Http/2 ...

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`OkHttp`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) with `Spring` for that:

```
@LocalServerPort
private int localPort;
@Autowired
private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;
private TestRestTemplate template;

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    restTemplateBuilder
            .requestFactory(OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory::new)
            .rootUri("http://localhost:" + localPort);

    this.template = new TestRestTemplate(restTemplateBuilder);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response ... 
This creates a only http2 restTemplate? Sorry I have never used OkHttp3 before.

Comment: hey, it will try by default to use http2 @thamurath

Comment: but I will need it to fail if it cannot use http/2 instead of going back to http 1.1, is that possible?